# Ramanujan's divergent series

Tags: riemann-zeta, divergent-series

I tried to prove this sum by myself, but I couldn't.
$1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + ... = 0$
First, I know this sums are a bit problematic, as we can't just $'='$ an infinite sum, but I would like to see the algorithm of proving the series above. Thanks.

Comment: One way is to use the analytical continuation of the $\zeta$-function, then use the fact that $\zeta(-2k)=0$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You are asking for why $\zeta(-2)=0$.  See [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272186/how-one-can-obtain-roots-at-the-negative-even-integers-of-the-zeta-function).  Also related is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112) where people ask why $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ if you are confused by the zeta function in the first place.

Comment: BTW it was not Ramanujan to first derive this expression, it was the master of us all Leonhard Euler himself :).

Comment: Isn't the sum $n(n+1)(2n+1)\over6$

Comment: The related _alternating_ series $1-4+9-16+\dotsb“=”0$ is easier.

Comment: @Colbi that is the sequence of *partial sums* $1+4+9+16+\dots+n^2$.  The question asker is however asking why $\zeta(-2)=0$ where $\zeta(s)$ is the analytic continuation of the function $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$.  Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Answer (score 1):

This is how Euler would have derived it using non-rigorous methods. The cool part about this non-rigorous method is that it leads to the same result as the rigorous "proof" by analyitical continuation for the $\zeta(s)$

Start with the geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots$$

Differentiate and multiply by $x$:

$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+\cdots .$$

Differentiate once again:

$$\frac{1-x^2}{(1-x)^4}=1+2^2x+3^2x^2+4^2x^2+\cdots .$$

**Note that I will use the congruent sign just to distinguish this from the normal equal sign.**

Now plug in $x=-1$ and don't care about convergence :D.
$$0=1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+\cdots \cong \eta(-2)  .$$

No try to establish an relationship to 
$$\zeta(-2)\cong1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+\cdots.$$

This can be achieved by subtracting $\zeta(-2)$ with $\eta(-2)$.
Or in general $\zeta(s)-\eta(s)=2^{1-s}\zeta(s)$ or
$$\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$

**Note that this representation is only valid for $s \neq 1$.**

From $\eta(-2)$ it follows that $\zeta(-2)=0$.

Comment: $s=1$ is a removable singularity of the RHS, and the equality is true in the sense $\eta(1) = \lim_{ s \to 1} (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)$